# Arrays within a method within another array Javascript/Action Script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to extract a restaurant menu tables in indesign using its language actionscript which is basically javascript. I need to store categories in which all have a bunch of items in which have their own proporties (itemName, itemDescription, itemPrice). My first approach was an array storing all the categories and then pushing a category method into the array {categoryName:'omelettes', items:[]} and now the problem arises of pushing the items inside menu[0].items.push{itemName:'Breakfast Omelette', itemDescription:'3 Eggs, Bacon, Swiss, Avocado', itemPrice:'8.99'}

I guess my question is can I do the following

[object, itemsArray[],object]

itemsArray[ {{itemName:'Breakfast Omelette', itemDescription:'3 Eggs, Bacon, Swiss, Avocado', itemPrice:'8.99'}},{{itemName:'Farmers Omelette', itemDescription:'3 Eggs, Ham, onions , Avocado', itemPrice:'7.99'}}]

```
var menu = [];
var handlers= {
        newCategory: function(categoryName){
                menu.push({
                categoryName: categoryName,
                Items:[],
                otherHeaders:[]
                })},
        newItem: function(itemName,itemDescription,ItemPrice){
                menu[0].items.push({
                itemName: itemName,
                itemDescription:itemDescription,
                ItemPrice:ItemPrice
                });
            }
}

handlers.newCategory('Omelettes');
handlers.newItem('Eastern Omelette','Green Peppers, Swiss, Bacon, Avocado','8.99');
alert(menu[0].categoryName);
```

Comment: Your property is named `Items` (capital "I") so you should be using `menu[0].Items.push()`

Comment: Yeah but that doesnt fix my issue. I dont think menu[0].items.push({.... is working properly. My script gets stuck on alert(menu[0].items[0].itemName); saying undefined is not an object.